# Why do I get this Incompatible Type error in OMNeT++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

This is the error:

> error: assigning to 'omnetpp::cMessage *' from incompatible type 'omnetpp::cMessage'`

This is my code:

```cpp
#include "computer.h"

Define_Module(Computer);

void Computer::initialize() {
    counter = 0;

    limit = 10;

    if (strcmp ("c1", getName())==0) {
       simtime_t F_delay = par ("F_delay");

       EV<<"Start Sending== \n";

       *msg = *createMessage();

        scheduleAt(simTime()+ F_delay, *msg);
    }
}

Computer::Computer() {
    my_msg = nullptr;
}

Computer::~Computer() {
  cancelAndDelete(my_msg);
}

void Computer::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {

    if(msg->isSelfMessage()) {
        send (msg,"out");
    }
    else {
        counter ++;
        if (counter == limit) {

            EV<<"Limit is expired \n";

            delete msg;
        }
        else {
            EV << " my name  "<< getName()<< " \n";

            EV << "counter = "<< counter << " \n";

            simtime_t delay = par("delay");

            scheduleAt(simTime()+delay,msg);

            EV << "sending again "<<" \n";
        }
    }
}

cMessage Computer::createMessage() {
    cMessage *msg = new cMessage ("HELLO");

    return *msg;
}

void Computer::sendCopyOf(cMessage *msg) {
    cMessage *copy= (cMessage *)msg->dup();
    send (copy ,"out");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should return a pointer, otherwise it is leaking memory

```
cMessage* Computer::createMessage() {
    cMessage *msg = new cMessage ("HELLO");

    return *msg;
}
```

This will fix the error you mentioned during this assignment

```
*msg = *createMessage();
```

which can just be

```
msg = createMessage();
```

and remember when you are done to `delete msg` or you will leak it.